# Is Instagram's Feed View based on UIWebView or UITableView?

Tags: iphone

It looks like UIWebView, but how do they implement that download progress bar and the section bar(very smooth scroll)...?

Comment: I know this is late, but I think I have an answer fo this

Comment: I worked on a test project a few weeks back to try to emulate this. I would say that there's a GOOD chance they're using UITableView with cached images and other hacks for it all.

Answer (score 4):

I have snooped around their logs, and I cannot guarantee that if the feed itself is a UIWebView, but it just so happened that when I went to the feed, a log message came up saying: "WebView loaded". This hints that they use a UIWebView for their feed.

I decided to do some research, and it seems I am not the only one who thinks that they might be using a UIWebView

http://www.lukew.com/ff/entry.asp?1499

Answer (score 3):

If they are using a `UIWebView`, you should be able to easily identify its traffic in a proxy such as [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com) or sniffing all network traffic using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org).

After putting Instagram though Charles, I see that its calling `http://instagram.com/api/v1/feed/popular/` which returns a set of JSON results.  This leads me to believe it is definitely not a `UIWebView` and something created in native code (almost certainly a `UITableView`.  As Andrew mentioned, the username UI elements behave exactly like `UITableView` section headers on a plain-style table.

Comment: Hmm..I guess so, maybe the WebView was for another part of the app.

Comment: It could also be an older version since your link was from Feb 2012.  A typical pattern is to release an app based on a `UIWebView` since development is usually faster (although performance is poor) and then go back and implement it natively in a later version once it gets more popular.

Comment: But my own snooping around logs was done today with their latest app, I just looked online to see if my suspicions were true. Anyways, often apps tend to have UIWebViews for terms of service, about us pages, etc, so maybe it's one of those things. @jszumski

Answer (score 2):

I would say it is almost definitly a UITableView.  Here's why I think this.

- The profile picture of the poster is shown at the top while scrolling in the exact same manner that a UITableView shows section headers. (As I see you already noticed)
- There is a slight delay when loading the next cell.

The scrolling is pretty smooth, but it would be smoother with continuous view (though it would take much more memory and the page would take longer to load).

What they probably do is pull information from the server and cache it in Core Data.  They populate the table from this until you click refresh or close and open the app, at which point they reload the data and refresh the page.  This includes comments, likes, descriptions and images.

The rest of it is choosing the right drawing methods to make the UITableViewCells as performant as possible.  I won't go into this here, but there is a lot you can do to make the scrolling smooth.

Answer (score 1):

@Neo

I've experienced the same gateway error as the screenshot from this article:

http://kennethormandy.com/journal/your-favourite-app-isnt-native

Safe to say their using UIWebView?

Answer (score 0):

The way Instagram does this has been meticulously optimized, so what I'm about to say hardly scratches the surface of all of the methods they used to make their feed work.

They start by checking for a cache, and if one is not present, they call to server. Server returns the first meta of objects, which are cached/stored to disk.

Then they pre-allocate the height of the cell based on number & size of comments.

Now they setup their IB & UI methods, and everything (for the most part) executes normally.

The only other main thing is that they use pagination. So they're caching/saving to disk with each pagination.

Again, this is just the surface. There are a ton of hacks implemented into the feed in order to make it work so well. If you are planning to replicate this with a very similar model (content, comments, profile images, etc), it's going to take you some time to get it right.

Comment: What's your source? @jsksma2